# Meta Query returns wrong number of posts

Tags: custom-field, get-posts, meta-query

I am using this meta query inside a category:

```
$args   =  array(
    "posts_per_page"    => 12,
    "post_type"         => array( "event", "post" ),
    "post_status"       => "publish",
    "category"          => $tid,
    'meta_query'        => array(
                                'relation' => 'OR',
                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'event_start',
                                    'value'     => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                                    'compare'   => '>=',
                                    'type'      => 'DATE'
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'event_start',
                                    'compare'   => 'NOT EXISTS'
                                )
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key'       => '_thumbnail_id',
                                'compare'   => 'EXISTS'
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'foreign_language',
                                'value'     => 0
                            )
);

$posts          = get_posts( $args );
```

It should return 12 posts, but return only 11. If I set `posts_per_page` to 13, it returns 12.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Change `$posts = get_posts( $args );` to something like `$posts_array  = get_posts( $args );` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$posts` is a reserved global variables which stores the value from the `$posts` property from the main query. By using `$posts` as a local variable, you are breaking the main query and the `$posts` global variable. This leads to unexpected output.

You should use unique custom variables as local variables. You can solve your issue by changing

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

to something like

```
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```